# Spring formatters for nulls values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a select control in my view and i want to "bind" or "format" the item "Please select an item" to a null value in my backing form object. 
Is that possible? because i know that making some traditional formatting doesn't work properly. 
Instead i saw an example of making changes in class GenericConversionService and using that class instead of the original. (unfortunately i can't find it anymore)

This is the exception when i return a null value from my formatter class:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value &quot;-1&quot; from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'com.tesisutn.restsoft.dominio.articulo.Marca'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can it not bind to a special `nullItem` backing object, for which you test and handle appropriately?

Comment: Like using Null Object pattern? and then inspect the object properties finding them and changing accordingly?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking; unless there's some reason that you specifically want it bound to `null`?

Comment: @eggyal thanks for the response, but it seems too much work doing this way. I want to persist objects with null references if the relationship is optional and non value was selected. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your form is sending a `-1` to indicate that "Please select an item" is selected.

- First thing you can try is to send noting. Then the binding (when the form is send to the server) will work, the according command object field will be null.

  ```
  <option value="">Please select an item</option>
  ```
- If this is no option for you (for example because you use dojo), then you need to implement your own [property editor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-beans-conversion) or [conversation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#core-convert) (Spring 3.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the way I was looking for. **value=""** was the correct answer. It was very easy indeed